# direct proofs of inequalities

Tags: inequality, proof-writing, soft-question

I completed an entire chapter set on direct proofs only to find my teacher said 
reject my answers due to a false method. what i did was assume the problem was true and then solved it as such and then wrote it backwards. Her exact words were you should only use this method to search for hints to achieve a direct proof, as it will help you gain the skills needed for these types of questions. Further, when attempting to solve these only work on one side - I did not know what this meant and still don't really: Also, how are you meant to prove a question if you are only working with one side?

Once taking this advice i found myself stuck on how to presume on the questions i had previously solved, as i would be trying to find out how to reduce the LHS to an acceptable answer only to which i found myself even more confused about how to pursue these questions. Not to my aid the tutorials on YouTube are not good, Hence, my asking for your help for essentially what are the rules when proving inequalities - and to clarify it is only the inequalities that i find difficult - when can you add, divide...etc, when can subtract from both side - LHS and RHS - etc...

if you could please answer me the basics that would be helpful!

thanks to anyone who actually took the time to read that lol !

for example:

Show that for all a, b∈R,   $$(\frac{a^2 + b^2}{2})⩾(\frac{a+b}{2})^2$$

which i answered as:

$$\frac {a^2 + b^2}{ab}-2 ⩾0$$

$$\frac {a^2 + b^2}{ab} ⩾2$$

$$ a^2 + b^2 ⩾2ab $$

$$ 2a^2 + 2b^2 ⩾ a^2 + 2ab + b^2 $$

$$\frac {a^2+b^2}{2}⩾ \frac{a^2 + 2ab + b^2}{4}$$

$$\frac {a^2+b^2}{2}⩾ \frac{(a+b)^2}{4}$$

Comment: I think I can guess what your teacher means, but without any *actual examples* what you did (and your teacher objected to) it's hard to say. Could you add such an example (possibly not an overly long one).

Comment: If I understand correctly, your mistake is something quite basic: what you have to remember is that while it is possible that something false implies something true, something true can never imply something false. In your case, starting backward is incorrect because in case the original statement was false, it won't *necessarily* lead to something false. What your teacher is trying to say is that this is a good method for exploring the problem, and simply writing your solution backward could be the correct answer.

Comment: im pretty sure the original question was true.

Answer (score 1):

Your first step is wrong for $ab\leq0.$

The right proof is the following.

We need to prove that
$$2(a^2+b^2)\geq(a+b)^2$$ or
$$a^2-2ab+b^2\geq0$$ or $$(a-b)^2\geq0,$$ which is true.

Id est, $$\frac{a^2+b^2}{2}\geq\left(\frac{a+b}{2}\right)^2$$ is true and we are done because in all lines we have equivalent statements.

Comment: how did you go from the first step to the second? did you get it by multiplying the LHS by the 4 in the RHS and the mulitplying the RHS by the LHS' 2 ? If so is that not assuming the question is true. Which brings me back to my question. What are the basics, what and when can you do to the change the original statement?

Comment: @progress They are equivalent. But it's enough to think so: For  proving of $\frac{a^2+b^2}{2}\geq\left(\frac{a+b}{2}\right)^2$ it's enough to prove that $2(a^2+b^2)\geq(a+b)^2.$

Comment: how are they equivalent?

Comment: Also how is $$a^2-2ab+b^2 > 0 $$ equivalent to $$ 2(a^2+b^2)≥(a+b)^2 $$

Comment: and by saying there equivalent are you not assuming the question is true?

Comment: @progress Let's understand this step by step. $2(a^2+b^2)\geq(a+b)^2$ is equivalent to $2a^2+2b^2\geq a^2+2ab+b^2$. Do you agree?

Comment: yes I do agree.

Comment: $2a^2+2b^2\geq a^2+2ab+b^2$ is equivalent to $2a^2+2b^2-a^2-2ab-b^2\geq0.$ Do are agree?

Comment: ahhhh i see now. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You have proved the inequality, *provided* that
$$
\frac{a^2+b^2}{ab}-2\ge0
$$
which is generally false and even meaningless when $a=0$ or $b=0$.

Note that, even for $ab\ne0$, you can't go from
$$
a^2+b^2\ge2ab
$$
to
$$
\frac{a^2+b^2}{ab}\ge2
$$
Try $a=1$ and $b=-1$, for instance.

A correct derivation would be
\begin{gather}
(a-b)^2\ge0
\\
a^2+b^2-2ab\ge0
\\
a^2+b^2\ge2ab
\\
2a^2+2b^2\ge a^2+2ab+b^2
\\
\frac{2(a^2+b^2)}{4}\ge\frac{(a+b)^2}{4}
\\
\frac{a^2+b^2}{2}\ge\frac{(a+b)^2}{2^2}
\\
\frac{a^2+b^2}{2}\ge\left(\frac{a+b}{2}\right)^2
\end{gather}

Comment: why you can't go from a2+b2≥2ab
to
a2+b2ab≥2

Comment: @progress For $a=1$ and $b=-1$, you have $a^2+b^2=2$ and $2ab=-2$; on the other hand, $\frac{a^2+b^2}{ab}=-2$ that's *not* $\ge2$.